# JavaScript setInterval and setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

The next code display the date every 1 sec and then stops.

```
(function() {
    var i = setInterval(function() {
        console.log(new Date());
    }, 1000);
    console.log("Hi");

    setTimeout(function() {
        clearInterval(i);
    }, 3000);
    console.log("Hola");
})();
```

Output:

```
Hi
Hola
Wed Oct 24 2012 13:35:27 GMT+0200 (CEST)
Wed Oct 24 2012 13:35:28 GMT+0200 (CEST)
Wed Oct 24 2012 13:35:29 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

But I don't know why `Hi` and `Hola` are displayed first. Also, why `setTimeout` is executed? It is not supposed that `setInterval` is executed every 1 sec and nothing else can be executed?. (Does the code above runs on the order in which it is written?)
Thanks.

Comment: All the code runs straight away.

Comment: No. `setInterval` and `setTimeout` return immediately, and your function continues. Execution of other code will be interrupted when the timeout expires at a later time to execute the code you provided to those calls.

Comment: @sje397 excution of the running code will not be suspended. Instead, the timed events are delayed if javascript is running at the time.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak Well you learn something every day :) Thanks.

Comment: This link could be useful http://www.phpied.com/sleep-in-javascript/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setTimeout` as well as `setInterval` only register functions (callbacks) but then go straight to the next command.

Therefor `Hi` and `Hola` are printed before the first callbacks are called.

First callback will be that of `setInterval` after 1 sec, then again after 2 sec.. After 3 seconds `setTimeout` kicks in and clears `setInterval`.

Comment: @enrmarc Yeah. You handle the fact that some time has passed.

Answer (score 4):

The comments show the execution order

```
(function() {                           // 0 anonymous function is called inline

    var i = setInterval(function() {    // 1 setInterval **schedules** the function 
                                        //     parameter to be executed every second
        console.log(new Date()); 
    }, 1000);
    console.log("Hi");                  // 2 Display 'Hi' on console

    setTimeout(function() {             // 3 **Schedule** the function parameter to 
                                        //     execute after three seconds
        clearInterval(i);     
    }, 3000);
    console.log("Hola");                // 4 Display 'Hola' on console
})();

                                        // 5 Display date from setInterval function

                                        // 6 Display date from setInterval function

                                        // 7 Display date from setInterval function

                                        // 8 Cancel setInterval executed from 
                                        //     setTimeout function
```

Hope this clears up your confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Everything out `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()` is executed anyway.
It's not the `sleep()` PHP's method... sadly!

However, this link could be useful: http://www.phpied.com/sleep-in-javascript/

Answer (score 2):

http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

Those two events are asynchronous. They are queued/executed at the next available moment, not at the exact time "setTimeout" or "setInterval" is called.

Comment: I counted twice in the first couple of paragraphs that article stating that they are not executed in a separate thread.

Comment: Not really another thread since JavaScript engines are single-threaded, but the link is a good insight nonetheless